# Tkinter ~ how to space out elements WITHIN a grid box

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

I am trying to space the following widgets out correctly so that they don't stack on top of eachother, but I don't know how to do it having them all within the same `.grid()` box. An example of the problem can be seen in the problem above.

To answer the question of why I can't just stick the widgets in the next row down: On the left, you can see that the listbox takes up significant vertical space. If I place the text widgets on the next row down, there will be a huge space inbetween the elements.

Here is the relevant code. For context, I am broadly working with receipts.

`test.py`

```py
receipt_number_input = Label(text="Receipt Number: ")
receipt_number_input.grid(row=0,column=3)
receipt_number_entry = Entry()
receipt_number_entry.grid(row=0,column=4)

order_total_input = Label(text="Order Total: ")
order_total_input.grid(row=0,column=3)
order_total_entry = Entry()
order_total_entry.grid(row=0,column=4)

date_input = Label(text="Date: ")
date_input.grid(row=0,column=3)
date_entry = Entry()
date_entry.grid(row=0,column=4)
```

I have looked into `padding` and `sticky` to shift the text down and into a more usable format, but none of them in my experience have fixed the problem.

What would I have to pass into `.grid()` to shift these boxes into their correct positions?

Comment: Try passing `ints` for `padx` or `pady` in `.grid`. You can also pass a tuple of 2 `int`s for `padx` or `pady`

Comment: `.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=3,pady=2)`. There seems to be no discernable difference

Comment: Try increasing `padx` and `pady`. Remember that it is in pixels and 3 pixels isn't noticeable most of the time.

Comment: `.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=500,pady=300)`. The entire thing is shifted now lol: https://gyazo.com/cc421abb4f16ff111aa3ea7969a80d6e

Comment: Also I just noticed you know how you call `receipt_number_entry.grid(row=0,column=4)` and `order_total_entry.grid(row=0,column=4)`? That puts the 2 widgets in the same location one on top of the other

Comment: That is correct. I am trying to get them to be one on top of eachother whilst being in the same row and column

Comment: Put them on different rows and add `rowspan=5` to the `.grid(...)` that you call on that `Listbox`/`Text` on the left

Comment: amazing, that worked